# How get specific value from list of string array

Tags: c#, list

I'm reading from csv file into a list in this way every row in the file is array cell and every cell is a array of columns .
this is my reading cod :

```
public List<string[]> parseCSV(string path)
    {
       List<string[]> parsedData = new List<string[]>();
        string[] fields;

           TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(path);
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            parser.SetDelimiters(",");

            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                fields = parser.ReadFields();
                parsedData.Add(fields);

            }

            parser.Close();

        return parsedData;
    }
```

In the end I got this list of string array . Now I want read specific value from specific cell and specific row from parsedData .
how can I do that ?

My problem is that my "row" that I want is a string value , the value that im looking for is from column number 1 and row value of "key".

Comment: Have you thought about flattening the list of arrays of strings into a List of strings?

Comment: `parseCSV("somePath")[0][0]`

Comment: `string Result = parsedData[RowIndex][ColIndex];`

Answer (score 2):

So you have a `List<string[]>` but dont know how to access a specifc "row" or "column" from it? You just need to use the indexer. Arrays/lists are zero indexed:

```
string field3OfRow4 = parsedData[3][2]; // can cause an IndexOutOfRangeException
```

You have to handle the case that there are less rows or columns. Therefore use the `Count` property of the list and the `Length` property of the array:

```
if(parsedData.Count >= 4 && parsedData[3].Length >= 3)
{
    // safe
    string field3OfRow4 = parsedData[3][2];
}
```

Of couse you can also use a loop.

Comment: Who's to say this isn't zero based?

Comment: @Curt: someone commented that this was field2 of row3 but that comment is now deleted. Just as my comment you are referring to.

Comment: My problem is that my "row" that i want is a string value , the value that im looking for is from column number 1 and row value of "key".

Comment: What means `row value of "key"`? Provide a little example.

Answer (score 1):

You can access your List and array based on index like:

```
string specificValue = parsedData[row][col];
```

But a better option would be to create a class for your CSV item. Then parse each row and create an object of that class, It will give you much more flexibility.

```
List<MyCSVItem> list = new List<MyCSVItem>();
```

and then while parsing, you can pass the `string[]` to your class constructor and add the object to `List<T>`

```
while (!parser.EndOfData)
{
    string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
    list.Add(new MyCSVItem(fields));
}
```

Comment: don't forget that i have the title row as my firs row

Comment: My problem is that my "row" that i want is a string value , the value that im looking for is from column number 1 and row value of "key".

Comment: @user2450821 See the edit in my answer, I added a block of code for this

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down:

We have a `List<T> list` and access an element (row) with `T row = list[y-1]` (zero-based)

In this case `T` stands for `string[]`, and we access an element with: `string field = row[x - 1]`

To sum up, we can do this:

```
List<string[]> rows = parseCSV("somePath");
//-----------
string[] fieldNames = rows[0]; //get first row
string firstFieldname = fieldNames[0]; //get first row's first column
//or shorter:
string firstFieldname = rows[0][0];
```

As requested, you can search for the value "key" in column 1 in this way:

```
for(int r = 0 /*change to 1 to skip first row*/ ; r < rows.Count; r++) {
    string[] entry = rows[r];
    string firstColumn = entry[0];
    if(firstColumn == "key") {
        Console.WriteLine("Found 'key' in first column of row " + r);
    }
}
```

You can evaluate your CSV content like that:

```
List<string[]> rows = parseCSV("somePath");
for(int r = 1; r < rows.Count; r++) {
    string[] entry = rows[r];
    if(entry.Length != fieldNames.Length) {
        throw new FieldAccessException("illegal field length at row " + r + ": " + entry.Length);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Row " + r + " = {");
    for(int f = 0; f < fieldNames.Length; f++) {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + fieldNames[f] + " = " + entry[f]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("}");
}
```